# Aperture showing videos with odd lines, how to see videos nicely in OSX?

Tags: video, quicktime, aperture

I imported my tennis couching videos to Aperture but Aperture shows them with odd lines while QuickTime Player more nicely shows them. Which software should I use for videos because Aperture is clearly not meant for this?

**Aperture**

> [image]

**QuickTime Player**

> [image]

*P.s. I imported my videos from Sony Nex-3N.*

Comment: Try VLC player and change the playback speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video appears to have interlacing encoded by the source recorder. You can use HandBrake to remove interlacing while re-encoding. Aperture, btw, is photo editing and management software. It may play video, but there are players that are far better suited to video, such as QuickTime, or VLC. VLC, btw, is a defacto standard, and usually the answer to the question: "what will play this odd video format I can't seem to view with any decoder I've tried?" VLC has streaming and encoding functions as well. Final Cut Pro will of course play videos, but it is a video editing suite first, not "also," which means it is rather heavy amount of software for such a light task as playing video. You seemed to have answered your own question, but I thought I'd give you better confidence in your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just went with Final Cut Pro: stored the videos to external HDD and then viewed them there with FCP. Also VLC player as suggested may be an option. Yet FCP is also for editing, VLC for playing. For this purpose just for analysing the shots, FCP and VLC may be a bit off-topic but they can nicely show videos.